# Clarifications about ActionBarCompat

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

Until now my Activity extended FragmentActivity and uses the ActionBarCompat. If i try to run my app on a smartphone with API level 10 (2.3.3) (or less i think) the ActionBar doesn't appear. To try to solve this problem i extended ActionBarActivity, BUT now i can't see the
items on it. I think i need to change this method:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

but i don't understand how.

This is the main:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.loris.stefano.easyroutes.MainActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/option_group_2"
    android:icon="@drawable/layers"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map_tipe_normal"
            android:title="@string/map_type_normal"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map_type_terrain"
            android:title="@string/map_type_terrain"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map_type_hybrid"
            android:title="@string/map_type_hybrid"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map_type_satellite"
            android:title="@string/map_type_satellite"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/map_type_none"
            android:title="@string/map_type_none"/>
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/draw_path_menu"
    android:icon="@drawable/draw"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/merge_markers"
            android:title="Merge Markers"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/draw_path"
            android:title="Draw Path"/>
    </menu>
</item>

<item
    android:id="@+id/track_options"
    android:icon="@drawable/import_map"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/import_track"
            android:title="Import Track"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/export_track"
            android:title="Export Track"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/download_track"
            android:title="Download Track"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: What's the content in R.menu.main? You might need to edit it to be compatible with ABCompat.

Comment: You're right. I edited.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770612/actionbarcompat-menu-item-is-not-showing

Comment: Ok now it's much better. But there are two differents problems now on the smarphone with 2.3.3. 1) The button on the map for find the position doesn't work. 2) My actionbar's background has vanished

Comment: Background is probably something with your theme. Button isn't in the question?

Comment: No no. I mean the GoogleMap's button to find your location.